# MATLAB : Compare each element of rx_bs with a threshold value of 0.50

Tags: matlab

Question : Create a vector of random numbers of size 1×20 and name it as `rx_bs`. Compare each element of `rx_bs` with a threshold value of 0.50. If the value of the element is greater than 0.5, it returns value 1, otherwise 0. Therefore, you will obtain another 1x20 vector, name it as `bs`.

My Answer:

```
rx_bs=rand(1,20);
threshold_c=0.5;
bs=[1:20];
for i=1:length(rx_bs)
    if rx_bs(i)>threshold_c
        bs(i)=1;
    end
    if rx_bs(i)<threshold_c
        bs(i)=0;
    end
end
rx_bs
bs
```

Why is this wrong?

Comment: I had to add an extra `end` to your code to make it valid. Does that make it work? Could you explain what the problem is? Also, a simpler solution is `bs=rs_bx>0.5`.

Comment: Ya it did .
adding an extra end and maybe intending it properly really helped ! :)